# Is there any shortcut to ajax delete request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there any shortcut to ajax delete or post request ?

I am trying this,

```
MyNamespace.WebServices = {
    ajaxDelete: function (url, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: done,
            error: fail
        });
    },
    // fairly similar for post
};
```

**Implementation**

```
MyNamespace.WebServices.ajaxDelete(
    url, 
    data, 
    function (data) {
        // do something
    }, 
    function (data) {
       // do something else
    }
);
```

I already know about `$.getJson` or is there any library out there I could use to shorten as I am making tens of requests in my code maybe more in future

Answer (score 1):

There is for [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) but not for DELETE.
Though it's possible to write it by yourself or search the web.
For example you can write the following:

```
$.delete = function(url, data, callback, type){

  if ( $.isFunction(data) ){
    type = type || callback,
        callback = data,
        data = {}
  }

  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: callback,
    data: data,
    contentType: type
  });
}
```

Taken from [here](http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2014/04/jquery-put-and-delete/).